# visual studio code: How to have case insensitive search in the current file?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I search in the currently opened filter from the sidebar, I get case insensitive search on all files. But If I search in the current file's search (ctrl+F / cmd +F), I get case-sensitive search results.

I always search in lowercase, so this approach can't find a lot of camelCase strings for me. How to have case insensitive search here?

Comment: `ALT + C` will enable/disable case sensitive search

Comment: Or press the "Aa" button inside the search field.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try turning off "match case" property by clicking to button highlighted in the image: [image: search by match case]

Comment: ya this would work for the sidebar & the file search as well. Thanks, Sevimli!

Comment: And there is also search the **whole word** besides it (Alt + W in Linux and Windows). If you want further search setting, you need the **regex symbol** besides it.